# How to pass a PHP array into a custom Wordpress table field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom Wordpress form and I am working on inserting the submissions into a custom table in my database. Passing single fields into the table is working great, but I also have an array I need to insert as well. I created a `LONGTEXT` field, but when I try to insert the array into the field nothing is getting inserted.

Here is my `$wpdb` insert code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? '';
$products = $_POST['products'] ?? '';

global $wpdb;
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix . 'orders';

$wpdb->insert($tablename, 
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'products' => $products
    ),
    array('%s', '%s')
);
```

The `$products` variable is the array. How can I make it so that the array gets passed in the `products` field of my custom table? Also, is `LONGTEXT` the correct field type?

Comment: There's several ways, but only two are "decent": One, use `serialize`.  What's nice about this is that WP uses serialize, and has a useful function called `maybe_unserialize` that is defensive / smart about unserializing data.  **However** -  I personally DO NOT like serialize, as it is fairly brittle and not readable.  Instead, I'd recommend using `json_encode`: `$string = json_encode( array('name' => $name, 'products' => $products));` - then insert `$string` into your `LONGTEXT` field.

Comment: @cale_b Thanks! `json_encode` worked great.

Comment: **TO BE CLEAR** - the answers in the duplicate link _are not great_.  Please read the comment here about serialize / json_encode, which would be preferable to many of the other answers at the duplicate...